# Filter data on cellFilter columns

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-ui-grid

I am using `type:'date', cellFilter: 'date:"dd.MMM.yy"'` in column definition of date fields. The actual received date is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Please find attached screenshots.

`cellFilter` applies very well here.

[image: grid with custom date filter]

Now as shown below if I type `02.` to filter it should display the results. But it's not showing correct results.

[image: grid date filter]

**How to display correct filtered results of columns with custom `cellFilter` applited on it ???**

Comment: `filterCellFiltered:true` works for such scenario. Thanks all for visiting the question.